# php read of a json file - i can not read the multi tier elements

Tags: php, json

I am trying to read a json file in php, i can retrieve the root parts of the file, however whatever i try, i can not read the innner parts(child) of the json file, any help would be great

here is the json file

```
    {
   "orderId":"112-1567223-2156269x",
   "legacyOrderItemId":"0218943273x4778",
   "orderItemId":"2068965x7409001",
   "asin":"B01K9RxxB0GQ",
   "title":"xippro decs",
   "merchantId":"A3H7UYG3T9xx6JDM",
   "quantity":1,
   "version3.0":{
      "customizationInfo":{
         "surfaces":[
            {
               "name":"Surface 1",
               "areas":[
                  {
                     "colorName":"White",
                     "fontFamily":"Coppergate Bold",
                     "Position":{
                        "x":13,
                        "y":218
                     },
                     "name":"Line 1",
                     "Dimensions":{
                        "width":382,
                        "height":53
                     },
                     "label":"Your Text Here",
                     "fill":"#FFFFFF",
                     "customizationType":"TextPrinting",
                     "text":"Ruth's"
                  },
                  {
                     "colorName":"White",
                     "fontFamily":"Coppergate Bold",
                     "Position":{
                        "x":144,
                        "y":258
                     },
                     "name":"Customization 2",
                     "Dimensions":{
                        "width":119,
                        "height":17
                     },
                     "label":"Date (EST)",
                     "fill":"#FFFFFF",
                     "customizationType":"TextPrinting",
                     "text":"1969"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "customizationInfo":{
      "aspects":[
         {
            "title":"Your Text Here",
            "text":{
               "value":"Ruth's"
            },
            "font":{
               "value":"Coppergate Bold"
            },
            "color":{
               "value":"#FFFFFF"
            }
         },
         {
            "title":"Date (EST)",
            "text":{
               "value":"1969"
            },
            "font":{
               "value":"Coppergate Bold"
            },
            "color":{
               "value":"#FFFFFF"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "version":"2.0"
}
```

and my php code is below

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('16532135318050.json', true);

$character = json_decode($file,false,400);

//print_r ($character);

echo $character->orderId . "<Br>"; 

echo $character->legacyOrderItemId . "<Br>"; 
echo $character->orderItemId . "<Br>"; 
echo $character->asin . "<Br>"; 
echo $character->merchantId . "<Br>"; 
echo $character->quantity . "<Br>"; 
echo $character->version3.0->customizationInfo->surfaces->areas[0]->colorName; // does not work
echo $character->version3.0->customizationInfo->surfaces->areas->colorName; // does not work



?>
```

Comment: all but the bottom 2 lines work

Comment: why not you just decode your Json and start fetching the child values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `version3.0` isn't a valid identifier - you should use `{"version3.0"}` instead.
2. `surfaces` is an array, so you should use `surfaces[0]`

this might work

```
$character->{"version3.0"}->customizationInfo->surfaces[0]->areas[0]->colorName
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because `$character->version3.0->customizationInfo->surfaces` is an array and needs to be dereferenced accordingly:

```
$character->{'version3.0'}->customizationInfo->surfaces[0]->areas[0]->colorName
```